# android build platform replace x86_64 to i686

Tags: android

I want to build android project source, and when I using below commands, it says the binary can't executed. I found the gcc binary is x86_64 platform, my laptop is i686 platform

```
adan@adan-Latitude-D630:~/androidsource$ source build/envsetup.sh
adan@adan-Latitude-D630:~/androidsource$ lunch full_eng
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file
 Enter a password: ^C
adan@adan-Latitude-D630:~/androidsource$ file prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0xf8e11f40cf6b10fa26e6fea774d9d94058c53595, stripped
```

I found my platform is:

```
adan@adan-Latitude-D630:~$ uname -a
Linux adan-Latitude-D630 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:25:33 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I want to replace the build binary with i686 platform,  how to do this?
any infomation and link is welcome
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per the slightly outdated documentation: http://source.android.com/source/building.html

and this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/gMW0TLIyr3o

you will need a 64 bit OS and as much RAM as you can get in order to build Android from source on the master branch, i.e. the latest and greatest code. i686 means 32-bit so if you are running 10.04 of Ubuntu, you could try to build Froyo (Android 2.2), but I would recommend more powerful hardware than a Dell Latitude as the building the Android source code could take a long time.